# Excel: Power Query refreshing issue after updating external CSV file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I realised after some period that I am having always the same issue when updating / refreshing my table. And that "issue" is - giving me empty cell for some rows even though it is populated with information.

So, I will explain in short: I am having couple of CSVs that are updated periodically (always the same matrix, so I wuould say unique table just sightly differ in abbrevations). And in Power Query I made that easily for everyone, where you need just a refresh basically to have everyting populated. But after a while I got a feedback that my table is wrongly populated some fields, or gave empty cell even if there are infos.

This picture down is just a small "cut" of data, where you can see a gap after updating my CSV file with a new file - **this field on 25 ZF0** has informations, but gives me this empty field anytime I am updating something new.  Sometimes on other fields too.

Has anyone similar problem? What can be in question? Can it be a problem in a column order? because from Power Query I am having slightly different order, and then I am matching certain columns and their values with Index/Match??

I am sorry I cant provide more pics, because I would need XY pics to take, that is a reason I just pointed on small issue that is occuring, hoping that someone might help.

I am using Office 2016.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I think I figured it out (at least one of the possible solutions). I calculated and formatted part of the data witohut using Power Query, so I calculated it "manually" and do the exactly the same ordering  - but now is populating properly, I checked on couple of examples, and the one wtih PQ is still making "gaps" and the one I created is as it should be. Strange actually, thought that PQ is almost 100% stable related to this.

Comment: There's likely an issue with your data or your PQ code. Obviously, I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you've provided. If you don't figure it out, suggest you read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question to supply extra information.